# How to use regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> get submatch's position of original string by the iterator itself?

Tags: c++, regex

Below is the code to find the match of "\b(sub)([^ ]*)" in "this subject has a submarine as a subsequence". But I also want to know the position of those sub matches in original string by regex_token_iterator itself. The result should be 5, 19, 34.

```
// regex_token_iterator example
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main ()
{
  std::string s ("this subject has a submarine as a subsequence");
  std::regex e ("\\b(sub)([^ ]*)");   // matches words beginning by "sub"

  // default constructor = end-of-sequence:
  std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> rend;

  std::cout << "entire matches:"; 
  std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> a ( s.begin(), s.end(), e );
  while (a!=rend) std::cout << " [" << *a++ << "]";
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

> Output:
>      entire amtches: [subject] [submarine] [subsequence]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*a` return a pair of two iterators over the string *s*. You could try this:

```
std::cout << " [" << *a++ << ' ' << a->first - s.begin() << "]";
```

or this

```
std::cout << " [" << *a++ << ' ' <<  std::distance(s.begin(), a->first) << "]";
```

Comment: The first only gives me a very high number, the seconds works. But only when `s` is `const`.

Comment: You can use `s.cbegin()` to make it work even if `s` is not `const`. I am not sure why the first snippet is wrong, but I would have recommended the second anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately I get "regex_token_iterator not dereferenceable" with both options.